# pass type to generic class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I am looping thru the ObjectStateEntry of EF so I can access enrty.Entity, I am doing some static validation on the poco classes and i want to also do business rule validation so i created a library to do that, now i have this line of code that expect a type excample Customer..

```
 MyEntityValidator<needtypehere> ev = new MyEntityValidator<needtyehere>(new EntityValidator());
```

so I am having problem passing type where i mentiened 'needtypehere'. I tried entry.Entity.GetType() but not working . Again this is the signiture of the method

```
GetErrors(this ObjectStateEntry entry)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To invoke generics from a `Type` instance, you would have to use:

```
Type closedType = typeof(MyEntityValidator<>)
         .MakeGenericType(entry.Entity.GetType());
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(closedType);
```

which is... awkward - as you then need to do lots of additional work with reflection. Alternatively, you can call into a generic *method* that does the code:

```
public static void InvokeGeneric<T>(...) {
    MyEntityValidator<T> ev = new MyEntityValidator<T>(
        new EntityValidator());
    ... etc; lots more code that uses ev
}
...
typeof(ContainingType).GetMethod("InvokeGeneric").MakeGenericMethod(
    entry.Entity.GetType()).Invoke(null, args);
```

Comment: @saurabh: Marc is correct; using a runtime type (an instance of the `Type` class) to get a reference to a generic type is awkward and generally not in the spirit of actual generics. If you control the type structure, then the fact that you need to do this (and can legitimately reference your class and interact with it in a type-agnostic way) means that there should probably be a non-generic base class, then generic subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx).